# php checking array for number

Tags: php, arrays

Whats the easiest and quickest way to loop through an array of numbers and find out if $val is in there?

Say my array is $numbers(3,5,78,35,78) and my $val=5, it would return true.

Comment: Both goleztrol and clive have the right answers. in_array is a simple true/false, while array_search returns the corresponding key if the value is found. Whichever of the two you use depends on what you need to do.

Comment: @MarcB In this case `in_array` is the best. I thought of it only after posting `array_search`, but since Clive suggested `in_array` as well by that time, I removed my answer.

Comment: @Golez: `in_array()` is basically `array_search(..) !== FALSE`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?

```
if (in_array($val, $numbers)) {
  // Do something
}
```

No looping required

Comment: What would be the correct syntax for: if (($key == "red") && (in_array($val, $numbers)))

Comment: Do you mean if "red" is a key of the array? If so just extend it with `array_keys`: `if (in_array("red", array_keys($arr))) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the position of your number, you could use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)