# Add multiple nids to an if function

Tags: php, if-statement

In a function in a custom module, I am using:

```
if ($node->nid == 210)
```

How do I alter it for multiple nids? Not just 210 but for say, nodes 210, 211, 225?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php checking array for number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959584/php-checking-array-for-number)

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array and use `in_array`

```
if(in_array($node->bid, array(210, 211, 225))) {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$list= array(200,400,300);

foreach($node->nid as $key)
{
   if(in_array($key, $list))
   {
        // Your Logic
   }
   else
   {
     // invalid id logic
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Or

```
if ($node->nid == 210 || $node->nid == 212 || $node->nid == 213)
```

This would exclude `211`. The `||` is `OR`

Comment: Is there _any_ reason to use this instead of in_array()?

Comment: Sure.  The question was how to modify the if statement to allow multiple nid's.  The question was not 'If I were willing to add more control structures, and know how to use foreach, and conceptually understand arrays, how could I do this?'  The OP didn't select anyone's answer as having helped him, so I added another solution that could meet his needs.